# How to get build variant output directory

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I need to run some tasks that occur after an Android project's assemble* task finishes. In particular, these tasks need to know what was the output directory for all the compiled classes for a particular build variant. How do I retrieve the output directory for an assembleFlavor1Debug task?

My current workaround is something like this (although this workaround presents problems of its own, like not being able to find the assemble tasks even though it's been placed after the android configuration block):

```
android.buildTypes.all { theBuildType ->
    android.productFlavors.all { theFlavor ->
        String capitalizedType = ... //Type name with first letter capitalized
        String capitalizedFlavor = ... //Flavor name with first letter capitalized
        ...
        project.tasks["assemble${capitalizedType}${capitalizedFlavor}"].configure {
            doLast {
                project.ext.variantOutput = "build/intermediates/classes/${theFlavor.name}/${theBuildType.name}"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

EDIT #1: I was able to fix my workaround. The major issue was that the Android assemble* tasks (assembleProdDebug, assembleProdRelease, etc.) were not yet created on the project, even though configuration was occurring after the Android configuration block. I was able to get the additional configuration on the assemble* tasks done by enclosing the entire code snippet above into a `gradle.taskGraph.whenReady {...}` block, but this did mean I lose out on the ability to continue configuring the dependency graph. Fortunately, not being to configure dependencies in my particular case was not a major loss; all I needed was the ability to record the last assembled build type and product flavor.

I'd also like to note that this behavior is with version 1.0.0 of the Android Gradle plugin. Although I have not checked, the absence of these Android tasks might not occur on newer versions of this plugin.

EDIT #2: So I've also tried version 1.3.0 of the Android Gradle plugin. I'd also like to note that this is the LIBRARY Android plugin, and not the application plugin (I suspect these missing assemble* tasks are not generated during project configuration for the application plugin as well, however).

Answer (score 2):

You might want to try instead of wrapping the entire thing with `gradle.taskGraph.whenReady` try using `afterEvaluate` closure.  The tasks should exist after the project is evaluated.

This means your closure would run at the end of the configuration phase and before the execution phase.  At this time all tasks would have to be registered.

```
afterEvaluate { project ->
    // do work on `Project` object just like normal
    project.android.buildTypes.all { theBuildType ->
        ...
    }
}
```

ref: https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/Project.html#afterEvaluate(groovy.lang.Closure)

Comment: Thanks! I can configure task dependencies with afterEvaluate(). It seems that somewhere between project configuration and execution of the afterEvaluate closures that the additional Android tasks are generated.